# Expected value of sum of weighted edges in a random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Assuming one has a directed weighted graph with n nodes and let us denote the weight going from node $i$ to node $j$ by $e_{ij}$. Then one can simply just sum all weights $e_{ij}$ up.

But if we are now in the set-up of a **directed** weighted random Erdos-Renyi graph $G(N,p)$ where $N$ stands for the number of nodes and $p$ for the probability having a link between two edges (just pick for simplicity one direction by probability $1/2$, as we are in a *directed* graph), how can I calculate the expected value of $\sum_{i=1}^N e_{ij}$ assuming that the weights $e_{ij}$ follow a given distribution?  (constant/uniform/normal ect)

Comment: Do you mean the *expected value* of the sum of the weights?  Otherwise, I don't understand why you can't just add up the weights.

Comment: @saulspatz yes, exactly! sorry I was not clear enough...

Comment: Please correct your question to reflect your comment.  The goal of this site is to establish a body of questions and answers that people can consult when they have math problems, so it's important that the questions be accurate, as well as the answers.

Comment: @saulspatz I edited it :) Thank you very much for your comments & your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a vertex $i,$ let $K_i$ be a random variable whose value is the number of edges incident from $i.$  By linearity of expectation, the expected value of the sum the weights on these edges is just $K_i\mu,$ where $\mu$ is the mean of the distribution of the weights.  Therefore, if $p_k=\Pr(K_i=k),$ then the expected value of the sum of the weights is $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kp_k\mu=\mu E(K_i)={\mu(n-1)p\over2}$$